# Accessing a file outside the web container in Jetty

Tags: web-services, servlets, jakarta-ee, gwt-rpc

I'm using Eclipse 3.6 in Windows XP SP3 to develop a GWT application. The application requires to display the contents of a folder with graphics that reside on server to the client. Also, the graphics folder is not inside the web container but in another place in hard disk.
Eclispe uses the Jetty HTTP server to run the web application. I use the following snippet in my RemoteServiceServlet to test the file access and to get the content of the text file.

```
File inputFile = new File("C:\\mytext.txt");
FileReader fin = new FileReader(inputFile);
char c[] = new char[(char)inputFile.length()];
int i;
i = fin.read(c);
s = new String(c);
```

Unfortunately i get an error, and i don't know how to translate it in order to correct the code (or any configuration files).

```
Initializing AppEngine server
Unable to access http://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck?runtime=java&release=1.5.1&timestamp=1308100600&api_versions=['1.0']
java.net.UnknownHostException: appengine.google.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.RemoteVersionFactory.getVersion(RemoteVersionFactory.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.checkForUpdates(UpdateCheck.java:99)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.doNagScreen(UpdateCheck.java:174)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.maybePrintNagScreen(UpdateCheck.java:142)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.maybePerformUpdateCheck(AppEngineLauncher.java:137)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:500)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1055)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)
Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Successfully processed C:\Documents and Settings\Giorgos\workspace\Zserver\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Successfully processed C:\Documents and Settings\Giorgos\workspace\Zserver\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
[ERROR] javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String mytest.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\mytext.txt read)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\mytext.txt read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:166)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at mytest.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many unrelated problems:

1. Given the stack trace in your question, you seem to be developing an application for Google App Engine. GAE doesn't allow accessing the file system, hence the AccessControlException you get.
2. A text file is not a graphics file. I don't understand what you're trying to do.
3. The line `new char[(char)inputFile.length()];` is wrong. Why are you casting the length of the file to a char?
4. The [read method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28char%5B%5D%29) doesn't guarantee that all the file will be read at once. It returns the number of read characters. You should not ignore the returned value. Read [the tutorial about IO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

Comment: :) as you can understand i'm beginner in this area. Is it possible to run my web application not for GAE ? The text file was just a test to see if i can access a file at all. If i put the text file inside the war folder then i can access the file, but because i will have to create folders and add files in them dynamically i certainly do need to access the file system. Can you please suggest me where to look in order to achieve that?

Comment: Follow the tutorial on GWT, and just avoid the part about using/deploying on AppEngine : http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html